# Unable to read characteristic using Bluetooth LE, readCharacteristic returns false on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to read blood pressure from Medisana device via bluetooth on my Android device.

Here is my code

```
override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
                        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)
                        if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered failed")
                            return
                        }

                        val characteristic = gatt?.getService(BLOOD_PRESSURE_SERVICE_UUID)?.
                            getCharacteristic(BLOOD_PRESSURE_CHARACTERISTICS_UUID)
                        if (characteristic == null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "blood pressure measurement characteristics is not supported by the device")
                        } else {
                            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)
                            val descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID)
                            descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE;
                            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)
                            if (!gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to read characteristic")
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Here are the constants I copied them from an official Bluetooth website

```
private val BLOOD_PRESSURE_SERVICE_UUID = UUIDUtils.convertFromInteger(0x1810)
private val BLOOD_PRESSURE_CHARACTERISTICS_UUID = UUIDUtils.convertFromInteger(0x2A35)

object UUIDUtils {
    fun convertFromInteger(i: Int): UUID {
        val MSB = 0x0000000000001000L
        val LSB = -0x7fffff7fa064cb05L
        val value = (i and -0x1).toLong()
        return UUID(MSB or (value shl 32), LSB)
    }
}
```

When the code is executed I see "Unable to read characteristic" in the logs. When I debug `readCharacteristic` it returns in the line

```
public boolean readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
```

So the characteristic is not readable, but how to make it readable. I am new in Bluetooth and all this stuff makes me confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
According to the document, blood pressure need to add indication enable to get the data.
So you need to: 
First, add "ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE" to the CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG descriptor.

This descriptor come from:

```
descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                    UUID.fromString(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG)); //CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG equal to 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Then:

```
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
```

And last step, write the descriptor to remote device (pressure master)
like this

```
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

This work for me, I get the blood pressure data from the devices.
 I'm not a native English speaker, sorry for my poor English